# convert list of strings to numpy list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm reading data (numbers) from a file into a list, as follows:

```
    weight_file = open(model_name, 'r').readlines()
    weights = weight_file[6:]
```

It seems that I can't read them straight into a `numpy.array` because the first rows of the file contains words.

So now, in `weights` I have a list as follows: `[['1 2 3'] ['4 5 6']]`

Now I want to convert it into a `numpy.array`. I tried this:

```
    weights_np = np.array([])
    for weight in weights:
        weights_np = np.append(weights_np, weight.split())
```

What this does is create a single vector: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, but I need it to be represented as some kind of matrix - like a list of lists. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `weights_np` is this:

```
In [23]: weights_np = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

then you could use `reshape` to make it 2-dimensional with 3 columns:

```
In [24]: weights_np = weights_np.reshape((-1, 3))

In [25]: weights_np
Out[25]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

But a more satisfying method would be to parse the file properly with `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt`. (This would be much much faster than using Python loops and calling `np.append`.) Note that these functions have a `skiprows` parameter which you could use to skip the first few rows:

```
weights = np.loadtxt(model_name, skiprows=6)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a "kind of matrix", simply use:

```
numpy.array([[int(val) for val in line.split()] for line in open(model_name)])
```

To get a simple vector, use:

```
numpy.array([int(val) for line in open(model_name) for val in line.split()])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> weights = ['1 2 3', '4 5 6']
>>> weights_np = np.array(map(lambda x: map(int, x.split()), weights))
>>> weights_np
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
weights_np = np.empty((0,len(weights[0].split())),int)
for weight in weights:
    weights_np = np.append(weights_np, [map(int,weight.split())], axis=0)
```

Demo:

```
>>> weights = ['1 2 3','4 5 6']
>>> weights_np = np.empty((0,len(weights[0].split())),int)
>>> for weight in weights:
...     weights_np = np.append(weights_np, [map(int,weight.split())], axis=0)
... 
>>> weights_np
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```